Psalm 139:13 says that God knits us in our mother's womb. If Jesus creates all things, and not God, then who knitted Jesus in his mother's womb?
Psalm 139:13-16 ESV

For you formed my inward parts; you knitted me together in my
mother’s womb.
I praise you, for I am fearfully and wonderfully
made. Wonderful are your works; my soul knows it very well.
My frame
was not hidden from you, when I was being made in secret, intricately
woven in the depths of the earth.
Your eyes saw my unformed
substance; in your book were written, every one of them, the days that
were formed for me, when as yet there was none of them.
How precious to me are your thoughts, O God!
How vast is the sum of them!

I am wondering this:
If all things are created through Jesus, then who knit Jesus' human body when he incarnated into his mother's womb?
And while Jesus was on earth, how could any creature be born, plants grow, or rain fall from the clouds? How could anything be created and maintained everywhere while Jesus was on earth while doing the will of and submitting to the authority of his Father, whom he called his God and our God?
Are we not understanding "through him" correctly?

You are missing the point - Jesus is God but not God the Father; just as God the Father is not Jesus but still God - there being only one God.  Please desist this pointless line of questioning.  Col 1:17 says that Jesus also sustains the entire universe - even when He was a man on earth and as a baby.  I do not understand this but accept the clear Bible teaching.  Note that the arbiter of truth is NOT human logic.

A related answer https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27051/what-does-john-13-mean-by-through-logos-everything-is-made

@Dottard. What is this arbiter of truth that you say is not "human logic"? If you yourself do not understand it why postulate the idea like you understand it? How can one assent to a teaching that one does not understand?

@AlexBalilo - the arbiter of truth is the Scriptures - some teachings I do not fully understand and neither does anyone else.  Indeed, anyone who claims a perfect knowledge of the Bible is lying.

@Dottard. Does God reveal to mankind truths that mankind cannot comprehend?

@AlexBalilo - it seems to me that God created all things initially through Jesus in Genesis, then God sustains creation in the 6,000 years since for Jesus.

@JoshuaB - except that Col 1:15-18 says that Jesus sustains all things

@AlexBalilo - there are many things revealed that humans will never understand such as: (1) The mystery of the resurrection 1 Cor 15:51, (2) the mystery of God's will (3) The mystery of Christ and His incarnation Eph 3:4, col 2:2, 4:3 (4) the mystery of Creation itself (5) the mystery of marital love Eph 5:32 (6) the mystery pf the Gospel of grace Eph 6:19, 1 Tim 3:9, 16, etc, etc.  There is also the profound mystery of God Himself - no one understand God; if we did we would be God.

t@Dottard."hat Jesus also sustains the entire universe - even when He was a man on earth and as a baby. I do not understand this but accept the clear Bible teaching" if you do not understand this, then why do you say that the bible teach it? The subject that you call mysteries are revealed, preached proclaimed by God's messengers. Why would God want us to reason with him if He is not a God of reason?

@AlexBalilo - God created the world through Jesus and for Jesus, and God sustains the world through Jesus and for Jesus. So God created and sustains all things, but He created and sustains all things through Jesus.

@JoshuaB. I would stop commenting for now until you provide evidence for your assertion.

WHO KNIT JESUS' HUMAN BODY?
Notice first that it is a human, the Psalmist, who is describing his birth, as being "knit." This is the normal description of all human being births. (See Isaiah 49:5, where Isaiah is also "formed in the womb.")
But Jesus birth was not an ordinary human birth! It was an incarnation. (John 1:14) That is, a temporary residence of God in human flesh. This was a unique event in the history of mankind. There is no other like it. Nor will there ever be one like it. Behold, a virgin shall be with child and bear a son. (Isaiah 7:14)
Secondly, note that the method of birth was not by human conception. Rather, the angel stated that "the Holy Spirit would overshadow her." (Luke 1:35) This was the same method by which life was given to the creatures during the Creation Week, mentioned in Genesis 1. The Spirit of God hovered over the water and land and creatures came to be.  So it was the Spirit of God (the third part of the Trinity) that formed a baby in Mary's womb.
There is a Father, and there is a Son; but we must not leave out the Holy Spirit when dealing with the amazing activity of God! It was the Holy Spirit's operating by which Jesus was Incarnated. The Holy Spirit is God, such that the writer of Hebrews could also write: You are my Son, Today I (God) have begotten you. (Hebrews 1:5)
Thirdly With Jesus on earth, creation of things could, and did, still take place. Notice what Jesus said as to how miracles took place: What I see my Father do, so I do. Jesus performed, as a surrogate, what God the Father had decreed, and had already empowered to be done. The "tabernacle-ing" of Jesus on earth in no way boxed in the power of God, when it came to creating.

I think you're missing the point. God commanded Jesus in the beginning to create all things, and then God sustains all life from that point forward. God made sure that Jesus was born successfully in the womb of his mother.

What about Adam created without a mother or father, not more unique than Jesus?  Or even Eve? Begotten to produce offspring, what you saying is God basically had a baby!

The Father still knit His own beloved Son in the womb of Mary, the mother of Jesus!
The scriptures apply to Jesus! Recall, He came to fulfill the law as the living Word. The Jews and teachers tried testing him so many times but since He's the Son of God and literally God, He always answered truthfully and full of knowledge and wisdom and they werr always confounded (confused and angry at being proven wrong and foolish) and often went to stone him or even kill him but he always got away..... until it was his time.
I too have often wondered at the language of "through". Through him, all things were made. What did this mean? How could something be created "through" Jesus?
We need to go through Jesus to get to thr Father. Jesus is the Way, the truth and the life and no one gets to the Father except through him.
So in this same line of understanding.....all things were made through him.
So does that mean Jesus made himself? Did Jesus knit together himself in the womb of Mary the virgin mother of God?
To the point of previous answers, Jesus was conceived of (by) the Holy Spirit, who is God, ordained by the Father, who sent His only Son.
The Father sent the Son to earth through Mary.
Jesus, the incarnation, is fully human and fully God, for the fullness of the deity lives therein-- meaning, within Jesus.
So, Jesus is eternal. For He is alpha and omega and His kingdom is forever. He was there in the beginning with God, and was God. For Jesus is the Word. And in the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God and the Word is God. JOHN 1:1
So, before Jesus came to earth, He must of agreed to come here with the Father and the Holy Spirit. For God is eternal and timeless and infinite and God is Sovereign. He knows all, and He is Loving and Pure Good.
So we know how much the Father loves His Son, because He tells us that in the gospel and in the bible.
The Father gave His Son His own spirit after He was baptized!
So who knit together Jesus in the womb of Mary? If Jesus is eternal, as a man is He a "created being"?
Well, Yes! Yes because, Jesus is given a human life, and a human body, and Jesus the human died on the cross as a man being fully God and this is how His blood was spilled for us. We know His precious blood was spilled for us the testimony is in the bible  of the water and the blood and the spear in His side and the wounds that remain in His hands and feet after He is resurrected as evidence He is truly the risen King.
Jesus and the Father are one. Jesus and the Father are one with the Spirit. The Holy Spirit is the Spirit of Jesus.
Jesus was made by the Holy Spirit.
And lovingly knit together in Marys womb by God, being God.
In a way, Jesus was made through Himself, since the Holy Spirit is His own Spirit ♡
trinity, 3 in 1. 3 separate persons, One God ♡ Thats why the statement "Jesus Christ the one True God" is true.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I see you want to apply Trinitarian theology to a Psalm written when the Trinitarian theology did not exist. The Trinitarian theology will have the upper hand in the argument because it had a much later say so in the understanding of the Psalm according to Trinitarian theology.
In strict Genesis terminology the words create, made, and form are not synonymous. Nothing can be made or formed until the creation. Creation is existence out of nothing. Made is manipulating the creation into something made. Form is to manipulate what is made into something formed. The creation must happen first. Then it can be made from what was created. And last it can be formed from what is made.
Example: first the dust must be created. Then the dust can be made into clay by pounding it into the smallest possible dust you can pound it into and adding water to the what is now clay.  Knead it into a large ball. Now the clay that has been made from the dust and water which have already been created can be formed into a clay pot by manipulating and working it into the desired shape and then cooking it in a really hot fire. You can see now all the steps involved to have a clay pot. The LOGOS is all those steps of made and form to bring the clay into being as a clay pot. The LOGOS cannot create the dust. The LOGOS only made the dust into clay and then the clay pot. When you apply the Father as the creator of the dust, the LOGOS as what made the dust into man, and the breathe of life, spirit of God as what keeps the man alive you have the Trinitarian theology.
God cannot create God because God has always existed. Therefore in Trinitarian theology Jesus had always existed because well simply Jesus is God and so God cannot create Jesus. Jesus cannot create Jesus. Hence it was the Father who created, not Jesus who created. John 1 specifically says all things were made through Jesus. It is not saying all things were created by Jesus. The thought of made through Jesus is the LOGOS. The LOGOS did not create. The LOGOS made. Without the LOGOS nothing can be made because the LOGOS cannot create.
What Psalm 139 is reasoning from is that all life is alive because of the breath of life, the spirit of God. It is the spirit of God keeping the living inside the womb alive, as much as it the breath of life keeping the trees alive and the birds alive. God created, made, and formed the everything. That is the reasoning coming from Genesis 6:3.
